# How does on implement Oracle Apex region authorization

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2

The bind variable :app_region_id works region however it does not work for the authorization scheme

***SQL statement for region***

```
SELECT  WORKSPACE,APPLICATION_ID , PAGE_ID, REGION_ID, REGION_NAME,AUTHORIZATION_SCHEME, :app_region_id
from apex_application_page_regions 
where region_id = :app_region_id
```

***Authorisation scheme***
**Scheme type:** Exists SQL Query
**SQL Query:**

```
Select  1
from apex_application_page_regions 
where region_id = :app_region_id;
```

which bind variable should I use to achieve region authorization. The code that I wanted to implement, it does not return the desired results

```
Select 1
    from AD_GRP_APEX_REGION_ASSOC r,
       AD_GRP_EMP e
    where  e.ad_grp = r.ad_grp
    and e.user_id =  :app_user
    and r.region_id = :app_region_id
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to accomplish. What is the desired outcome.

Comment: Do you want to compare user_id to :app_user? I don't understand the requirement... authorization scheme will work when your query returns data.

Comment: the actual authorization query  will be  Select 1
    from AD_GRP_APEX_REGION_ASSOC r,
       AD_GRP_EMP e
    where  e.ad_grp = r.ad_grp
    and e.user_id =  :app_user
    and r.region_id = nv('app_region_id') 
;

Comment: AD_GRP_APEX_REGION_ASSOC  contains the region_id and the active directory group that will access the region.     AD_GRP_EMP contains the active directory groups and the userid associated to that group

Answer (score 0):

The variable `:app_region_id` is not a global variable in the same way as `:APP_USER`. Authorization schemas only work with global variables which are associated to the SESSION, not to a element in a page ( such is a region ). Besides that, it does not make any sense to have it because you use AUTHORIZATION SCHEMAS to limit access to different components in your application. Let me show how to apply authorization schemas to regions in Oracle Apex.

Let's imagine I have a test application with three regions:

- Region 1 shows one field of a query ( one row )
- Region 2 shows another field of a query ( one row )
- Region 3 only shows a message ( static content )

Without any authentication schema, it shows this

[image]

Now, let's create an authorization schema example that derives who is the user and based on this will show only region 3. In my case my application uses the authentication schema by default ( apex users ) so the user logged is always assigned to the global variable `:APP_USER`.

Application Builder --> Shared Components --> Authorization schemas

```
Authorization Schema --> MY_TEST
Type --> Exist SQL QUERY 

select 1 from dual where exists  ( select user_name from apex_workspace_apex_users where workspace_name = 'MY_WORKSPACE' and user_name = upper(':APP_USER') )
```

This authorisation schema will forbid to see a region when the user exists, so basically for everybody, obviously I am doing it just for testing purposes.

Then I modified attributes of REGION 1 and REGION 2 , changing the authorization schema to MY_TEST

[image]

Now, when I execute the application , I can only see the region3 in the page.

[image]