# How to send parameters to authorization scheme based on different regions in oracle apex

Tags: authorization, oracle-apex, access-control, role-based-access-control

My authorization scheme has plsql function call like **access_control.region_no_display(:role, :region_static_id)** has a parameter called region_static_id which is region static id.
Now from every region I call this authorization scheme and want to set value to region_static_id pageitem.

How to achieve this.. since I cant send different parameters based on different region static id.

Comment: I believe this question had already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148102/how-does-on-implement-oracle-apex-region-authorization

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain the business problem you're trying to solve rather than the technical implementation you've chosen?  My guess is that you're trying to set up a system where admins can allow or deny access to regions in your app without needing an APEX developer to make any changes.  My first thought would be not to use an authorization scheme.  In the Server-Side Condition, you should be able to use the :app_region_id in a call to a proc similar to `region_no_display` and use that to look up the static ID in `apex_application_page_regions`.